Precise characterization of simple functions belong to $L^p$.
Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space e and let $p\in [1,\infty)$ be a real number. I would like to characterize the simple functions that are in $L^p(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$.
It's easy to prove that for a simple function $\varphi\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ results that
$$\varphi\in L^1(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)\iff \mu(\{x\in X\; |\; s(x)\ne 0\})<\infty$$
Now we suppose that $\varphi\in L^p(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ where $p>1$ and let $\varphi=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\chi _{A_k}$ where the $A_k$ are disjoint and such that $X=\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$, then we have that $$\int_X\lvert \varphi \rvert^p\; d\mu=\sum_{k=1}^n\lvert c_k\rvert^p\mu(A_k)<\infty$$ this implies that $\mu(A_k)<\infty$ for all $k$, then $\mu(\{x\in X\;|\; s(x)\ne 0\})<\infty$.
On the other hand if $\mu(\{x\in X\;|\; s(x)\ne 0\})<\infty$, then $$\int_X \lvert s \rvert^p\; d\mu=\int_{\{X\;:\; s\ne 0\}} \lvert s \rvert^p\; d\mu \le (\max_{k=1,\dots, n}|c_k|)^p\mu(\{X\;|\; s\ne 0\})<\infty$$ and therefore $\varphi \in L^p.$ Thus we have prove that $$\varphi\in L^p \iff \mu(\{x\in X\; |\; s(x)\ne 0\})<\infty$$

At this point, is it correct to say that a simple function belongs to $L^p$ for $p>1$ if and only if it is in $L^1$?


Yes. An alternative to what you did is to use the first result and notice that then $$\varphi\in L^p\iff\lvert\varphi\rvert^p\in L^1\iff\mu(\lvert\varphi\rvert^p\neq0)=\mu(\varphi\neq0)<\infty\iff\varphi\in L^1$$
